# Why is Visual Studio 2010 not saving Environment General settings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My installation of VS 2010 does not appear to be saving settings in the Environment section (Recent files, show status bar checkbox, etc).  Other settings do save properly, though (Auto Recover, etc).

Any ideas?

My Environment:
Windows XP
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Team Explorer, TFS2010 Power Tools
Visual Studio 2008 and 2005 installed as well
Works on my XP laptop.  The one difference between the two that I can think of is that I added the VS Theme extension on the workstation that I am having an issue on.  Don't know if that fouled anything up in the registry.
When I modify the settings (like the number of items shown in Window menu input), the settings are not saved to the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/VisualStudio/10.0/General/WindowMenuItemCount)

Comment: Nope, never. Seriously. Can you give us a detailed description of your environment?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's not saved to the registry would seem to indicate a larger problem than just VS.  I would recommend using a tool like Process Monitor to see if it's attempting to write to the registry.  Add a filter for devenv.exe and search for the registry key you're looking for.  In this case, immediately after clicking okay after you set the number of "Recent Files - items shown in Window menu" in Tools->Options->Environment->General, you should see a write (Success) in the registry under that key (WindowMenuItemCount).